# Why does freeing the memory lead to segmentation fault?

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I´m desperate because this code form time to time gives me a segmentation fault and I have no clue why. Actually it´s only supposed to add some linked list notes, print them and then empty the list by freeing the memory.

```
struct int_list {
   int value;
   struct int_list *next;
};
typedef struct int_list IntList;


void list_print(IntList *start)
{
   IntList *cur = start;
   while(cur != NULL)
   {
      printf("%d\n", cur->value);
      cur = cur->next;
   }
}


void list_append(IntList **start, int newval)
{
   IntList *newel = malloc(sizeof(IntList));
   newel->value = newval;
   newel->next = NULL;

   if(*start == NULL)
   {
      *start = newel;
   }

   else
   {
      IntList *cur = *start;
      while(cur->next != NULL)
      {
          cur = cur->next;
      }

      cur->next = newel;
   }

}


void list_free(IntList *start)
{
   IntList *prev = start;                           // prev = start
   while (start != NULL)                            // if start != Null
   {
       start = start->next;                         // make start point to the next element
       printf("Deleting %d\n", prev->value);
       free(prev);                                  // delete the previous element
       prev = start;                                // make previous point to start again
   }
   printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // fill the list
   IntList *start = NULL;
   list_append(&start, 42);
   list_append(&start, 30);
   list_append(&start, 16);

   // print the list
   printf("\nList 1\n");
   list_print(start);
   printf("\n");

   // free the memory and print again
   list_free(start);
   printf("Empty list:\n");
   list_print(start);
   printf("\n");

}
```

Everything was working just fine before I tried to implement list_free(). So I strongly assume the error can be found in this function. Just posting the rest of the code as well because I´m new to structures and am not 100% sure about having handles them correctly. Do you know what I´m doing wrong?...

Comment: Tip: `void list_print(IntList *start) { IntList *cur = start; ... }` can be written as `void list_print(IntList *cur) { ... }`

Comment: After calling `list_free()`, start is a dangling reference.   The following call of `list_print()` therefore has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `list_free` gets its argument by value. So the function deals with a copy of the original pointer to node. As a result the original pointer to node `start` stays unchanged.

And as a consequence the output of the list after calling the function `list_free`

```
list_free(start);
printf("Empty list:\n");
list_print(start);
```

has undefined behavior.

The function should accept the original pointer to node by reference as the function `list_append` does.

For example

```
void list_free( IntList **start )
{
    while ( *start != NULL )
    {
        IntList *prev = *start;                     // prev = start
        *start = ( *start )->next;                  // make start point to the next element
        printf("Deleting %d\n", prev->value);
        free(prev);                                  // delete the previous element
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Call the function like

```
list_free( &start );
```

After exiting the function the original pointer `start` will be equal to `NULL`. That is the list will be indeed freed.

This is better than when the client of the list shall explicitly set the pointer to `NULL` himself. He can make the same error as you did forgetting to set the pointer to NULL.

Answer (score 4):

You have undefined behavior because of dangling pointer

```
   list_free(start);
```

That is, `start` is still pointing to freed memory which you are trying to access.

You need to set `start` to `NULL` after `free`ing.

```
   list_free(start);
   start = NULL;
   printf("Empty list:\n");
   list_print(start);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is still pointing to the memory location of the deallocated memory, which is also an instance of segmentation fault.
It is "undefined behavior" and can cause arbitrarily unpredictable things to happen as the contents of pointed location are unknown, varying runtime.